# Powerapps: Use a button to upload a file to a specific folder in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, file-upload, powerapps

I've made a powerapp that writes information to an excel spreadsheet but I also want to add a button to the app that will prompt the user to upload pictures or documents to a PARTICULAR FOLDER ON SHAREPOINT. Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to have the button in Power Apps to take users to the SharePoint Folder.

The code in the OnSelect property of the button would then be:

```
Launch("htts://youtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/yourlibrary/yourfolder")
```

And if the library or folder need to be different from, you can use paramenters for it e.g.

```
Launch("htts://youtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/" & varLibrary & "/" & varFolder)
```